# Virtual TreeView selection width with toUseExplorerTheme

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, virtualtreeview

When I use `toUseExplorerTheme` in `TVirtualStringTree.PaintOptions` it draws the selection like this:

[image: Illustration of selection with toUseExplorerTheme]

Notice that the selection extends from the left side of the control to the position of the rightmost extent of any node caption; the selections are all the same width.

I want it to look as in this image ([someone else's project](http://www.anse.de/programming/), using Virtual TreeView), where the selection covers only the text of the node caption:

[image]

Unless there is a regression in Virtual TreeView (I'm using 5.2.2) then this must be possible, but I cannot find the right combination of options.

Here's my set-up code:

```
fTree := TVirtualStringTree.Create(Self);
fTree.Parent            := Self;
fTree.Align             := alClient;

fTree.OnGetText         := TreeGetText;
fTree.OnInitNode        := TreeInitNode;
fTree.OnInitChildren    := TreeInitChildren;
fTree.OnChange          := TreeSelectionChange;
fTree.RootNodeCount     := 1;
fTree.DrawSelectionMode := smBlendedRectangle;

fTree.TreeOptions.PaintOptions     := fTree.TreeOptions.PaintOptions
                                      + [toUseExplorerTheme];
fTree.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions := fTree.TreeOptions.SelectionOptions
                                      + [toMultiSelect];
```

Comment: Ragged edges on multi-select? Yikes.... Tastes differ I guess, but it is going to look, well... untidy? +1 For a well put question though.

Comment: @Marjan, variety is the spice of life :-)

Comment: @MarjanVenema An alternative is Explorer-style selections that span the entire width, but then it's harder/impossible to click outside the selection to deselect all. Anyway, I like the ragged right edge.

Comment: No worries. Though you might get flamed at [ux.se] for that :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, [`that was my fault`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19030907/960757). The statement I've suggested in [`this issue`](https://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/issues/detail?id=376) should have rather be:

```
procedure DrawBackground(State: Integer);
begin
  // if the full row selection is disabled or toGridExtensions is in the MiscOptions, draw the selection
  // into the InnerRect, otherwise into the RowRect
  if not (toFullRowSelect in FOptions.FSelectionOptions) or (toGridExtensions in FOptions.FMiscOptions) then
    DrawThemeBackground(Theme, PaintInfo.Canvas.Handle, TVP_TREEITEM, State, InnerRect, nil)
  else
    DrawThemeBackground(Theme, PaintInfo.Canvas.Handle, TVP_TREEITEM, State, RowRect, nil);
end;
```

The same applies also to the next nested procedure `DrawThemedFocusRect`. The fix is now commited to the [`revision r587`](https://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/detail?r=587), so please update your Virtual Treeview. Thanks to [@joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1823341/joachim-marder) for cooperation!

Comment: @Joachim, wow, that was quick. However, could you do the similar also to the `DrawThemedFocusRect` nested procedure, please ? I was going to submit an issue today since I was busy yesterday. Thank you and sorry for this issue!

Comment: Thanks. I found this in my first hour of using Virtual TreeView and couldn't seriously believe I had found a bug no one else had noticed! Turns out I was wrong this time ;-) Not sure my question deserves quite so many up-votes though… Virtual TreeView must be a nightmare to test with so many configurable options.

Comment: @TLama: Done also for DrawThemedFocusRect() in r587. Would you mind reviewing the code change?